# Need info on google contacts sync

Tags: android

In android...once logging in into the google account after all the contacts from google server is synced is there any intent being broadcasted by the google mail app which tells
that the google contacts are synced from the server? 
Could someone provide some info on this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no intent.

ContentResolver notifies any registered ContentObserver objects, whenever changes to the content they observe occur.  This happens regardless of whether the change occurd via local editing or via a sync operation.  Anything that derives from CursorAdapter will register automatically as a ContentObserver and so will be notified.  When it is, it will requery its cursor to update the associated ListView with the changes.  This only occurs if the associated ListView is active, onscreen, etc.  If not, there's no need to update.

Given the Android activity model, starting a new intent after every sync seems wasteful.  Why do you want to be notified if your app isn't active?